# Currency regex in Angular

Tags: regex, angular, currency

I need Help for currency regex in Angular.
I'm not really good at regex.

What I want is a regex that:

1. allows comma as digital-group-separator, but not in the beginning or the end.
2. allows only 2 digits rounded after decimal point.
3. allows only one decimal point and not in the beginning or the end.
4. not allows 0.00 or 0.

This is my regex:

```
(?=.*?\d)^\$?(([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)|\d+)?(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

but this regex allows 0.00

any one here please help thanks

Desired Outputs

Valid:

> 1,000.00
>
> 1000
>
> 0.01
>
> 24
>
> 1,234,000
>
> 11,222,245.22

Not Valid:

> ,000.00
>
> ,,,,,9
>
> 0
>
> 0.00
>
> 1,22,2,
>
> 1,000.
>
> 123,123,22
>
> 000,300.00
>
> 000300.00
>
> 000,123
>
> 000,000
>
> 00,000
>
> 0,000

Comment: Not na angular user but maybe `^\$[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?$` would work?

Comment: It's better to provide some input and desired output

Comment: @mjrezaee yeap ill try to provide a desired output pls wait.

Comment: `/^(?![0.]+$)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y4wgDj/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what does this (?![0.]+$) do? please explain it to me Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?![0,.]+$)(?:0|[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y4wgDj/5)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![0.,]+$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are one or more `0`, `,` or `.` chars till end of string
- `(?:0|[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*|[1-9]\d*` - either of the three alternatives:

  - `0` - zero
  - `|`  or
  - `[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*` - one to three digits with the first one being non-zero, and then 0 or more repetitions of a comma and then three digits
  - `|` - or
  - `[1-9]\d*` - 1+ digits with the first one being non-zero,
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of a `.` and then 1 or 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: how about this one "00012300.00" i want this to be invalid. i still cant do it T_T lols

Comment: sorry i cant upvote your answer cuz it still accept 
000,000.00

000,000.00

0,000

Comment: Just add a comma to `[0.]` -> `[0.,]` and you should be good to go

Comment: @unamen I added those fixes to the solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Okay thank you very much!! I'll try this one ^_^

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. How about this one last problem, it still accept 000,300.00. Help me pls im so noob i cant still figure out how to solve this one.

Comment: i would like to know your inputs guys. I currently changed the regex into this one "^(?![0.,]+$)(?!0+[1-9])(?:[1-9]{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$"  and i think this one solve my problem. But i want your confirmation guys cuz you're my master ^_^

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew done! sorry i forgot to accept the answer